# Google Maps Cannot Remove Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with removing a markers on google maps. These markers are created everytime the user creates a waypoint. They have the same position as the waypoint. These markers also have an InfoBox with a button to remove the correct waypoint and marker.

Everytime a waypoint is created I push a marker to one array and an infobox to the other.

This works if I have only one waypoint. The marker and waypoint are removed. But once I have 2 or more it does not work anymore. Once I try to remove one of the waypoints the marker stays on the map, even though I call .setMap(null) and/or .setPosition(null). Everytime I remove a marker I also remove it, the waypoint and info box from their corresponding arrays. Strangely enough, when I call a function to redraw the path, the waypoint does not exist anymore (as planned), but the marker stays.

Here is the code:

```
 var markers = {        
    waypoints:{            
        p:[],
        i:[],
        m:[]
    }
};
var saveWaypoints = function(){
        removeWaypoints();

        var points = directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints;        

        for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position:points[i],
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png',
                id: i
            });

            var infobox = new InfoBox({
                id: i,
                position: points[i],
                disableAutoPan: true,
                boxStyle: {
                    background: "white",
                    opacity: 1,
                    width: "289px",
                    border: 0,
                    padding: 0
                },
                zIndex: 1E4,
                isHidden: false,
                pane: "floatPane",
                enableEventPropagation: false,
                content: 'Pozicija: ' + points[i]               
            });            

            infobox.open(map,marker);
            infobox.hide();

            google.maps.event.addListener(infobox,'closeclick',function(){
                markers.waypoints.m[this.id_].setMap(null);
                markers.waypoints.m[this.id_].setPosition(null);

                markers.waypoints.m.splice(this.id_,1);
                markers.waypoints.p.splice(this.id_,1);
                markers.waypoints.i.splice(this.id_,1);

                drawPath();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
                markers.waypoints.i[this.id].show();
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
                if(markers.waypoints.i[this.id] !== undefined){
                    if(!markers.waypoints.i[this.id].keepOpen()){
                      markers.waypoints.i[this.id].hide();  
                    }
                }
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
                if(waypointDialog !== null){
                    waypointDialog.doNotClose(false);
                    waypointDialog.hide();
                }

                console.log(this.id);

                waypointDialog = markers.waypoints.i[this.id];
                waypointDialog.doNotClose(true);
            });

            markers.waypoints.m.push(marker);
            markers.waypoints.i.push(infobox);
            markers.waypoints.p.push({
                location: points[i],
                stopover: false
            });
        };            
    }; 

    var removeWaypoints = function(){
        if(markers.waypoints !== (null||undefined)){
            markers.waypoints.p = [];
            markers.waypoints.m = [];
            markers.waypoints.i = [];          
        }      
    };
```

Comment: Clearing the array will not remove the markers from the map, you must iterate over `markers.waypoints.m` and set the map-property of each marker to `null`

Comment: I did, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Comment: to remove a marker from map, you need to set the map property to null. Use setMap method from google.maps.Marker to set it

Comment: I did, but the marker stays on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because every time its loop, it is creating a marker which is the reason why you cannot access the previous marker, in your code, i think only the last created marker is accessible, to access all marker you should put it inside array after declaration. Try this code

```
var markers=[]; //initialize it on global

//and on creating marker, inside for loop add this code.
markers.push(marker);


//and to clear the markers in map try the code below
for(var i=0; i< markers.length; i++)
{
  markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```